# set function for div javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have this code, (this is not my code)
Demo online:
http://jsfiddle.net/xdUBZ/1/

```js
function run(interval, frames) {
    var int = 1;
    
    function func() {
        document.body.id = "b"+int;
        int++;
        if(int === frames) { int = 1; }
    }
    
    var swap = window.setInterval(func, interval);
}

run(1000, 10); //milliseconds, frames
```

```css
#b1 { background: hsl(0, 50%, 50%); }
#b2 { background: hsl(30, 50%, 50%); }
#b3 { background: hsl(60, 50%, 50%); }
#b4 { background: hsl(90, 50%, 50%); }
#b5 { background: hsl(120, 50%, 50%); }
#b6 { background: hsl(150, 50%, 50%); }
#b7 { background: hsl(180, 50%, 50%); }
#b8 { background: hsl(210, 50%, 50%); }
#b9 { background: hsl(240, 50%, 50%); }
#b10 { background: hsl(270, 50%, 50%); }
```

I have one problem, I want to set this function to div not to body.

I have tried with `document.getElementById` but not work, How can I do this, set this function to tag (div)?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us *your* code, the code you tried?  How did `document.getElementById` "not work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use classes, not ids.
It's because when you change the id to apply css no longer target it. And ids are not for this purposes.

```css
.b1 { background: hsl(0, 50%, 50%); }
.b2 { background: hsl(30, 50%, 50%); }
.b3 { background: hsl(60, 50%, 50%); }
.b4 { background: hsl(90, 50%, 50%); }
.b5 { background: hsl(120, 50%, 50%); }
.b6 { background: hsl(150, 50%, 50%); }
.b7 { background: hsl(180, 50%, 50%); }
.b8 { background: hsl(210, 50%, 50%); }
.b9 { background: hsl(240, 50%, 50%); }
.b10 { background: hsl(270, 50%, 50%); }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function run(interval, frames) {
    var int = 1;
    
    function func() {
        document.getElementById("layer").className = "b"+int;
        int++;
        if(int === frames) { int = 1; }
    }
    
    var swap = window.setInterval(func, interval);
}

run(1000, 10); //milliseconds, frames

</script>
 <div id="layer">content</div>
```